# Basic == overloading fails

Tags: ios, swift, operator-overloading

My desired end result is to be able to compare to `[Server]` objects for equality, like so:

```
let server1 = Server(username: "1")
let server2 = Server(username: "2")

let server1Array = [server1]
let server2Array = [server2]

print(server1Array == server2Array)
```

---

I have a class called `Server`, and I want to overload the `==` for **arrays** of `Server`:

```
// Server.swift

import Foundation
infix operator ==: AssignmentPrecedence

class Server: ServerRepresentable {
    let username: String

    init(username: String) {
        self.username = username
    }
}

// This protocol's only purpose is to allow me to use the `where` clause in the extension below 
protocol ServerRepresentable {
    var username: String { get }
}

extension Array where Element: ServerRepresentable {
    static func == (lhs: Array<ServerRepresentable>, rhs: Array<ServerRepresentable>) {
        let server1Usernames = lhs.map { $0.username }
        let server2Usernames = rhs.map { $0.username }

        // ERROR: Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Bool'
        return server1Usernames == server2Usernames
    }
}
```

As you can see, I get the error *"Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Bool'"* when I try to perform `server1Usernames == server2Usernames`, which are both arrays of strings. This is strange because the `==` operator should already come overloaded in `[String]` comparisons.

What gives? Is the compiler getting confused because I'm overloading the operator in this class?

Comment: I think the solution suggested by @LeoDabus is the right way to go but if you want keep the extension then you need to change the `where` clause to `where Element == ServerRepresentable` and of course change the return type of == to be Bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to extend Array. Just make sure your `Server` conforms to `Equatable` protocol:

```
class Server: ServerRepresentable, Equatable {
    let username: String
    init(username: String) {
        self.username = username
    }
    static func == (lhs: Server, rhs: Server) -> Bool {
        lhs.username == rhs.username
    }
}
```

---

```
let server1 = Server(username: "1")
let server2 = Server(username: "2")

let server1Array = [server1]
let server2Array = [server2]

print(server1Array == server2Array)  // "false\n"
```

---

Regarding your question you forgot to add a returning type `Bool` but the error displayed by the code you have posted should be **Unexpected non-void return value in void function**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this does not work. Taking advantage of `Equatable` initially seemed like the path of least resistance, but I have a basic unit test where I initialize two servers with the exact same `username`, place each one in `array1` and `array2` respectively, and `XCTAssert(array1 == array2)`. The test fails, leading me to believe that `==` is being used to compare the memory addresses of the objects instead of the actual values.

Comment: isEqual is not the same as ==

Comment: I revised my comment. `==` is what I actually used

Comment: @iOShitIScrewedUp This is definitely what you need to do. Just make your class conform to `Equatable` and compare the collection with `==` operator. You need to provide a [mcve] so that I can edit revise my answer based on it.

Comment: I found out why this wasn't working. My MVE is a minimized version of my actual code. My actual code's `Server` class is an `NSObject`, which already implements its own `isEqual` function and thus conformance to `Equatable` is redundant and not allowed. I solved this problem by simply overriding `isEqual` with my desired behavior. Still, your answer makes sense and should apply to most people experiencing a similar problem, so I'll accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**This only works for string, int, double, float arrays.**

You could try something like this

### To check if there is a difference

```swift
            for server1 in servers1 {
                        var name1 = [String]()
                        var name2 = String()
                        
                        for server2 in servers2 {name1.append(server2.name)}
                        
                        name2 = server1.name
                        
                        if name1.contains(name2) {
                            print("found duplication")
                         
                        }
```

### To find the differences

```swift
for server1 in servers1 {
                        var name1 = [String]()
                        var name2 = String()
                        
                        for server2 in servers2 {name1.append(server2.name)}
                        
                        name2 = server1.name
                        
                            print(name1. difference(name2))
}
// 
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func difference(from other: [Element]) -> [Element] {
        let thisSet = Set(self)
        let otherSet = Set(other)
        return Array(thisSet.symmetricDifference(otherSet))
    }
}
```